# This jQuery toggleClass behaviour seems strange, am I doing this correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a CSS rule for hiding elements with a class="hidden" and I'm using jQuery to toggle this class on and off on whatever ID i click on so I can make elements disappear.

Why does this not work?

```
$(this).attr('id').toggleClass("hidden");
```

but this does?

```
var x = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
$(x).toggleClass("hidden");
```

I know that the id is being taken correctly on the first example, but it seems that to toggle the class I have to add a "#".  I haven't seen any examples of others having to resort to this so I'm wondering what madness I have here.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
$(this).toggleClass("hidden");
```

`$(this)` is the actual element you're working with, so you can use this to directly toggle classes with.

In your examples, `$(this).attr('id')` is a string, and not an element.

This code works, because you're taking the ID (As a string), and selecting the ID on the webpage.:

```
//Store the id into a string
var x = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
//Pass the ID back into jQuery, and find the element
$(x).toggleClass("hidden");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).attr('id').toggleClass("hidden");
```

You are chaining events here. `$(this).attr('id')` already returns you a string. So you are technically doing `"someid".toggleClass("hidden")` which doesn't makes sense.

In your second example, you are actually selecting the same element again via id and firing your method, which is right

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

`.attr('id')` returns a string, not an element.

Let's pretend your element has an ID of `myThing`. Here's what your code translates to:

```
// 1
"myThing".toggleClass("hidden");

// 2
var x = "#myThing";
$("#myThing").toggleClass('hidden');
```

But really, if you're getting the ID from `this`, there's no reason to extract the ID in the first place. Just use `this` directly.

```
$(this).toggleClass('hidden');
```

Comment: How would that be possible @Turnip?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!